# Incomprehensible ratsnest in Kicad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

In PCBnew, there is a ratsnest that I cannot comprehend why its there. This is it:

[image]

As you can see, there is supposedly connection between pins 3 and 4.
However, if you look at the schematic, pad 4 is NOT connected to the non ground pin of the capacitor:

[image]

EDIT: This is the symbol of the IC:
[image]

Comment: Look at the symbol and make sure there isn't an invisible pin, or a duplicate pin 4. Also check for a stray track or something hidden under the pad in pcbnew.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks for the comment. I am not sure what you mean... I opened up the symbol but it didn't seem like there was a duplicate pin. I updated the question with a picture of the symbol.

Comment: Post a picture of the pin table for that symbol.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica This is the first time I hear of that term. Is there a button for it, inside symbol editor?

Comment: Did you try running a DRC ? That may point out a crossed trace or net.  Did you edit the schematic after starting to route? That could also leave wayward traces in bad positions. To check for a small piece of misplaced trace under a pad go to the side Appearance tool, select the Objects tab, then either switch off the Pads view (eye) or set the opacity slider to get a partial transparent view.

Comment: They're both assigned to the same net; I would try removing all the connections to both pads in schematic view, updating the PCB, verifying that the pads change nets, and then re-connecting the pads on the schematic and updating the PCB.

Comment: @vir I did just that and the ratsnest was removed. If you want, you can make an answer so I can upvote and mark as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both assigned to the same net; I would try removing all the connections to both pads in schematic view, updating the PCB, verifying that the pads change nets, and then re-connecting the pads on the schematic and updating the PCB.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the middle picture.  There is a line with "GND" just above it.  It is possible that this line got named GND.  To test this idea there is a button that selects nets.  Select the pin3 net and all lines with that name will light up.  If pin3 and 4 both light then you know the problem.

[image]

It is very likely that while editing the PCB you left a very short trace under pad3 or pad4. You need to turn off the pads to see what is under it, or move the IC and look for a very short trace left behind. The extra trace will have a net name of GNS or the net name of the trace on pin3.